# Display ads on post in a particular category

Tags: functions

I wanted to  display ads on in post in a particular category. I also want to display ads in another category not only one but every time I insert the code again and change the category id, it causes a "white screen" error. Can you tell me how can I extend that function, that I will be able to display different ads in different post in a particular category?

Below is the function that i use to display the ad:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'wpse_ad_content');

function wpse_ad_content($content)
{
    if (!is_single()) return $content;
    if(!in_category('7')) return $content;
    $paragraphAfter = 2; //Enter number of paragraphs to display ad after.
    $content = explode("</p>", $content);
    $new_content = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($content); $i++) {
        if ($i == $paragraphAfter) {
            $new_content.= '<div style="width: 300px; height: 250px; padding: 6px 6px 6px 0; float: left; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 18px;">';
            $new_content.= '//Enter your ad code here....';
            $new_content.= '</div>';
        }

        $new_content.= $content[$i] . "</p>";
    }
    return $new_content;
}
```

Comment: The link you provided is not valid. Can you please copy your code here to see what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

This code put where when you display your ads.

```
<div>
    <?php 
        global $post;
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'post' );
            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
                    break;
                }
            if($product_cat_id=='18'){
                // your ads code put here for this categories
            }else if($product_cat_id=='19'){
                // your ads code put here for this categories
            }
            else{
                // your default ads when categories not found then it display.
            }
    ?>
</div>
```

**MY Updated code :**

```
function wpse_ad_content($content)
{global $post;
    if (!is_single()) return $content;
    if(!in_category('13')) return $content;
    $paragraphAfter = 2; //Enter number of paragraphs to display ad after.
    $content = explode("</p>", $content);
    $new_content = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($content); $i++) {
        if ($i == $paragraphAfter) {
            $new_content.= '<div style="width: 300px; height: 250px; padding: 6px 6px 6px 0; float: left; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 18px;">';

                $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );
                foreach ($terms as $term) {
                    $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
                        break;
                    }

                if($product_cat_id=='13'){

                    $new_content.= 'aaaaa';
                }else if($product_cat_id=='19'){
                    // your ads code put here for this categories
                    $new_content.= 'bbbb';
                }
                else{
                    // your default ads when categories not found then it display.
                    $new_content.= 'cccc';
                }
                $new_content.= '</div>';
        }

        $new_content.= $content[$i] . "</p>";
    }
    return $new_content;
}
```

NOTE : Change your categories id.

Comment: Thanks for your code, please how can I make the ads shows up after a particular paragraph

Comment: review this : http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-insert-ads-within-your-post-content-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

You can not use this code twice, since it's declaring a function, and declaring a function twice with the same name will trigger a fatal error. If you want to extend the function, you can use it this way:

```
if(!(in_category('7') OR in_category('8') OR in_category('9'))) return $content;
```

This will show the ads on these 3 categories.

Comment: Thank you all for your reply,but please is it not possible to display ads based on a particular category at after a particular paragraph. For example, display a different ads on seo category, different ads on wordpress category..... something like.